# IllegalStateException when trying selecting photo from Google Photos app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This code used to work fine with the Nexus 5 image gallery.  Ever since moving to the newer Google Photos app selecting images crash this code.

**Error:**

> 08-07 10:10:10.792  25086-25086/com.app.app E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to
>   read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 7 columns.
>   08-07 10:10:10.795  25086-25086/com.app.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting
>   down VM 08-07 10:10:10.801  25086-25086/com.app.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.app.app, PID: 25086
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/17870/ACTUAL/1285012603
>   flg=0x1 (has clip) }} to activity
>   {com.app.app/com.app.app.PhotoActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized
>   correctly before accessing data from it.
>               at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>               at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
>               at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
>               at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
>               at com.app.app.PhotoActivity.getRealPathFromURI(PhotoActivity.java:456)
>               at com.app.app.PhotoActivity.onActivityResult(PhotoActivity.java:436)
>               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

**ONACTIVITYRESULT:**

```
case ACTION_SELECT_PHOTO: {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
        File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI)); // LINE 436
        mCurrentPhotoPath = imageFile.toString();
        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            setPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

**GETREALPATHFROMURI:**

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx); // HERE IS THE ERROR: LINE 456
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'd guess my issue is in one of two places, either `getContentResolver().query` needs to use some newer method.  OR the `getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)` MediaStore is the incorrect way to deal with the newer cloud based photo apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URI does **not** mean there is a file. An app is able to provide the contents through any mechanism it wants (a local file, a local file in a private directory you can't read, streamed over the internet, built dynamically on the fly).

Instead, you should use [ContentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) to get the contents from a URI. You can then transform that into a Bitmap via [BitmapFactory.decodeStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream))

Comment: Should I do the `ContentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)` in my `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Yes, you can use it right after your `Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData()` line.

Comment: This is random, but do you know how to create a new bitmap from an existing while setting options as well?  Before updating to this code I used `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f, bmOptions);` the main option sent is `inSampleSize` for scaling purposes.  I've looked into `createScaledBitmap` but that just uses height and width.

Comment: `inSampleSize` is only available with the `decodeZZZ()` methods because it does not require reading the whole Bitmap into memory. If you already have a Bitmap, you already have it in memory and you can use `createScaledBitmap()` with the height/width divided by 2, 4, etc to accomplish the same thing.